# HTML and CSS Javascript Jquery

Tags: html, css

How can I float my Facebook like page to right side on fixed position? I tried a lot using different position it worked but not on Fixed position.

Comment: you should have to use **float: right;**

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS for Facebook like page Wrapper

```
position:fixed;
right:0px;
top:25px;
width:100% !important;
```